# Writing Exercise: April 2014 (Volunteers)

Tags: discussion, chat, writing-exercise

### April 2014:

Volunteers willing to lead the chat on Tuesdays during the writing exercise hour? Or people who are willing to sign up and try and participate?

As a suggestion, people interested in leading a session may **answer** with the date on which they would like to, and people who are free (for a particular session) could **comment**.

P.S: This is based on a proposed answer [here](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/818/status-of-the-weekly-writing-exercise/822#822). If the community disapproves, it can be removed.

Comment: I can lead it today.

Comment: @NeilFein Sorry I missed it. Damned internet connection. Here is a log of the chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/168/conversation/april-2014-week-1-writing-exercise